# YouTube API - no parameter for channel logo?

Tags: c#, api, youtube

Is there anyway to retrieve the channel logo/icon/avatar that you see underneath the video player via the You Tube Api?

I can't seem to find the parameter.

`channels.brandingSettings.images` only contains banners in all resolutions and something called 'watch icon', but no channel logo sadly.

Where I can find the channel logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`channel.snippet.thumbnails` might be what you're looking for: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.thumbnails

Comment: You're right, thanks! Bad naming on YouTube's part though.